# What is the equality of ratios?

Tags: math-history, rational-functions

**Equality** among **ratios**. what is it called?  is **Proportion** the answer?

Comment: I cannot make sense of the question. A proportion basically is an equality between two ratios, that is, A:B = C:D.

Answer (score 1):

Some discussion of Eudoxus and theory of proportion can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudoxus_of_Cnidus).  The Greeks used the notation $A:B::C:D$ to denote proportion.